# ExePackage does not run elevated although PerMaschine is set to "yes"

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, elevated-privileges

In my WIX-Bundle, i have an `ExePackage` like the following:

It executes a ConsoleApplication which tries to open an write to a HKLM-Registry entry which fails when triggered out of the bundle. In cmd, everything works fine when executed as admin:

```
<ExePackage Id="SqlServerAuthConfig"
                  DisplayName="Configuration of SQL-Server Auth-Mode"
                  Compressed="yes"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Vital="yes"
                  Name="DatabaseMigrator.exe"
                  SourceFile="Migrator/DatabaseMigrator.exe"
                  InstallCommand="-ac -s &quot;localhost\SQLEXPRESS&quot;>
    <Payload Compressed="yes" SourceFile="Migrator/Common.dll" />
    <Payload Compressed="yes" SourceFile="Migrator/NPoco.dll" />
    <Payload Compressed="yes" SourceFile="Migrator/NLog.dll" />
</ExePackage>
```

Is there anything that could prevent this package from being executed with eleveated privilieges that i am not aware of? Also, is there a way to get th econsole-output (console-log) of the app into the bundle log for better debugging?

**Edit**

This is an except from the Bundle-Log regarding the execution of the `ExePackage`:

```
[1760:1510][2015-05-27T08:14:26]i301: Applying execute package: SqlServerAuthConfig, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\55E9EE89B506B4D626529F73B05E246CA13BE84B\DatabaseMigrator.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\55E9EE89B506B4D626529F73B05E246CA13BE84B\DatabaseMigrator.exe" -ac -s "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"'
[1760:1510][2015-05-27T08:14:30]e000: Error 0x80070003: Process returned error: 0x3
[1760:1510][2015-05-27T08:14:30]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to execute EXE package.
[091C:0094][2015-05-27T08:14:30]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[091C:0094][2015-05-27T08:14:30]i319: Applied execute package: SqlServerAuthConfig, result: 0x80070003, restart: None
[091C:0094][2015-05-27T08:14:30]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to execute EXE package.
```

Comment: Which version of WIX are you using?  Could you post the part of the burn log which shows the burn engine running the `ExePackage`?  Do you have specific evidence to show the `ExePackage` is not being run elevated?

Comment: thanks for your response. I habe posted an excerpt from the log. No i do not have no specific evidence, but taking away admin privileges is the only way to reproduce the behaviour which i am aware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem relates to `DatabaseMigrator.exe` not running elevated.  The burn engine uses the WIN32 API `CreateProcess()` to run `ExePackage`, so the `ExePackage` runs at the same privilege elevation as the burn engine, which is "Administrator".

The return value from running the execute package `SqlServerAuthConfig` is: 0x3.  This could be a WIN32 error or a value returned from the main function of the console program.  As a WIN32 error, the value 0x3 corresponds to "The system cannot find the path specified.", which could be from `CreateProcess()` or from `DatabaseMigrator.exe`.  Suggest double checking file paths relating to `DatabaseMigrator.exe`.

The `InstallCommand` attribute doesn't look well formed.  Should this be:

```
InstallCommand="-ac -s &quot;localhost\SQLEXPRESS&quot;">
```

Is there a way to get the console output?  For WIX 3.9 and earlier this is not possible.  The burn engine uses the WIN32 API function `CreateProcess()` to run the `ExePackage`, but the `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput` and `hStdError` handles are not hooked up to anything in the call, so all output is lost.

Comment: thanks for the answer. as for the InstallCommand, this is actually just a copy-paste failure of mine which i just corrected in the question. The error code is pretty surely returned by my app (`Environment.Exit(3)`)...

Comment: You were right, it ran with elevated privileges. this was not the problem. Thanks!